# Deleting a line in a txt file that contains a certain string

Tags: python

I want to search a text file for the user input and delete the line that contains it.Below is the text file.

course work.txt:-

```
Eric/20/SL/merc/3433
John/30/AU/BMW/2324
Tony/24/US/ford/4532
Leo/32/JP/Toyota/1344
```

If the user input is 'Eric', I want the line containing 'Eric' to be deleted and then the text file to be saved as below

Updated course work.txt:-

```
John/30/AU/BMW/2324
Tony/24/US/ford/4532
Leo/32/JP/Toyota/1344
```

Here is the code I created for that with the help of the very very small knowledge I have and some websites.

```py
with open('course work.txt','r') as original:
    #get user input
    word = input('Search: ')
    # read all content of file
    content = original.read()
    # check if string present in file
    if word in content:
        print('User input exsists')
        confirmation = input('Press enter to delete')
        if confirmation == '':
            import os
            with open('course work.txt', 'r') as original:
                with open('temp.txt', "w") as temporary:
                    for line in original:
                        # if user input contain in a line then don't write it
                        if word not in line.strip("\n"):
                            temporary.write(line)
            os.replace('temp.txt', 'course work.txt')
     else:
        print('Driver doesn't exsist')
```

What's happening here is,

1.open the course work.txt and read it

2.get the user input and search course work.txt for that user input

3.if that user input is found in the course work.txt, open a new file called temp.txt

4. write the all lines except the line that contains the user input into temp.txt

5.over write temp.txt on course work.txt

When I run the code it gives me a 'PermissionError: [WinError 5] ' error.The temp.txt file get created. It contains all the lines except the line i want to delete which is great, but it doesn't over write on the original file. Is there way to solve this or is there a more PYTHONIC way to do the exact same thing?

Comment: Don't use nested `with`, open the file once in read and write, while reading it save it in a variable, once you are done with the changes overwrite the file

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to take care of that and also by making good use of `shutil` to copy temp.txt after writing in order to update source-work.txt .

```py
import shutil


def modify_original_file():
    word = input('Search: ').strip().lower()

    track = 0
    with open("course-work.txt", 'r') as original:
        with open("temp.txt", "w") as temporary:

            # read all lines of file
            content = original.readlines()
            
            # check if string present in file
            word_found = False
            for line in content:
                if word in line.lower():
                    word_found = True
                    break

            if word_found == True:
                print('User input exist')
                confirmation = input('Press Enter to delete: ')
                if confirmation == '':
                    for line in content:
                        if word not in line.lower():
                            temporary.write(line)
                            track += 1
            else:
                print("Driver doesn't exist")

    if track > 0:
        # Update course-work.txt by copying temp.txt file
        shutil.copyfile("temp.txt", "course-work.txt")

modify_original_file()
```

**Terminal:** Enter `Eric` or `eric` for search.
Search: eric

**Output:** updated source-work.txt:

```
John/30/AU/BMW/2324
Tony/24/US/ford/4532
Leo/32/JP/Toyota/1344
```